# How to animate a JS-generated SVG object?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

This snippet of Javascript creates a circle object, but does not animate the circle. In Chrome, I can use the developer tools to edit the HTML (add some whitespace; nothing material) and that seems to convince Chrome to animate.

How do I force the animation to start?

```
function f(x, y) {
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

  var circle = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
  circle.setAttribute('r', '50');

  var animation = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'animatemotion');
  var path = 'm 0,0 l ' + (x + 500) + ',0'
  animation.setAttribute('path', path);
  animation.setAttribute('dur', '30s');
  animation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');
  circle.appendChild(animation);

  svg.appendChild(circle);
}

f(50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element creation seems to be case sensitive

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3GyJ/5/)**

look at this line

```
 var animation = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'animateMotion');
```

replace animatemotion with **animateMotion**

code

```
function f(x, y) {
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

  var circle = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
  circle.setAttribute('r', '50');

  var animation = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'animateMotion');
  var path = 'm 0,0 l ' + (x + 500) + ',0'
  animation.setAttribute('path', path);
  animation.setAttribute('dur', '30s');
  animation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');
  circle.appendChild(animation);

  svg.appendChild(circle);
}

f(50, 50);
```

initially I thought it was [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13585) bug, after checking a few examples I've tried with the casesensitive and I realized that it worked